# Im trying to receive input from the user but I keep getting this error. Why do I get this error?

Tags: python

[Why do I get this error and how can I fix it? Please & thanks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyyQM.png)

Comment: Please stop using Python 2 now! Really! Python 2 is dead (unsupported) since the beginning of 2020 and that was announced over 10 years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error comes from the fact that you are running Python 2 (which is now obsolete, consider upgrading to Python 3), where `input` reads a string from `stdin` and then `eval` it. To have the desired effect (that is, what you would get in Python 3 with `input`), you should use `raw_input` instead.